# Using PDO named parameters throws error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "(": syntax error

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo

I am attempting to update my SQLite database using:

```
$insertion = $db->prepare("UPDATE roles SET ($set_string) WHERE entryDate = :entryDate AND name = :name");
$insertion->execute($assoc_data);
```

Here `$set_string` is a string of attributes and parameters, which are what I want. A `print_r()` of `$set_string` yields:

```
name = :name,
entryDate = :entryDate,
development = :development,
adhoc = :adhoc,
mentoring = :mentoring,
documentation = :documentation,
codeReview = :codeReview,
meetings = :meetings,
learning = :learning,
waste = :waste,
workPrioritization = :workPrioritization,
management = :management,
applicationTraining = :applicationTraining
```

`$assoc_data` is an associative array with all the data that I want to update the database with:

```
Array (
    [name] => Bobby Bob
    [entryDate] => 2015-08-11
    [development] => 0
    [adhoc] => 0
    [mentoring] => 0
    [documentation] => 0
    [codeReview] => 0
    [meetings] => 0
    [learning] => 0
    [waste] => 0
    [workPrioritization] => 0
    [management] => 0
    [applicationTraining] => 100
)
```

I get the following error:

> Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "(": syntax error

Could someone pinpoint what the error is? I guess I don't quite understand how to use named parameters.

Comment: [Placeholders needs to be **unique**!](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: I don't think you need the `(` and `)` in your statement

Comment: @Rizier123, what do you mean by unique placeholders? If you are referring to the `entryDate` and `name`, then I replaced them with hardcoded '2012-08-11' and 'Bobby Bob'--and this didn't work.

Comment: @fibono You can't use them twice, this means unique. You can only use one unique placeholder only once for one value. But right now you use them twice in your query.

Comment: @Rizier123, I see. However, I got rid of the `entryDate` and `name` from my SQL "SET" field. I still get the same error.

Comment: @fibono Read that comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944102/php-pdo-named-parameters-not-working?noredirect=1#comment51798277_31944102 ?

Comment: @fibono FYI: reopened the question and cleaned your question a bit. Also added an answer just to give you some link to the documentations and explain a bit extended what the problem is and how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your first problem is, that your [`SQL UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) syntax is wrong. You don't need to use parentheses, as you can see from the documentation:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

Second placeholders have to be unique. This means you can only use them once for one value.  As you can read in the PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

> You must include a **unique parameter marker** for each value you wish to pass in to the statement when you call PDOStatement::execute().

And last `name` is a [mysql reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html), so you *should* put `` ` `` around it.

Means first remove your parentheses and second use unique placeholders (You can't have 2x `:name` and `:entryDate`) and put your backticks around reserved words.